# Php Laravel relationship error with json type data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship

I have `reported_id` of posts which is reported by many users with its id `reporter_id`, I have a column of reporters in the table of reports in which maximum four reporters's id can be stored. Reporters's id's belongs to anther table named users which contain personal information of reports. Now I am trying to make a relation with reporters with user but due to json type data of reporters I am unsuccessful

```
public function reporters()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Repoters', 'latest_reporters', 'id');
    }
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\User', 'latest_reporters', 'id');
}

$column = [\DB::raw("*"), \DB::raw("id as postable_id"),
            \DB::raw("report_type as postable_type")

    ];
$data = Repoters::select($column)
                ->with("reporters")->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(50)->unique("reported_id");
```

Comment: Could you further describe the problem? What errors occur?

Comment: I have 1 table named reports in which have a column named reporters which is save users id's as json . i want to make relationship these reporters with users but not making understanding how to make relation with reporters json data with users table

Comment: Dont put those ids into one column. Create a link table between those two.